# Weird corollary of Stirling's formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Stirling's formula gives us that there exists constants $c,C >0$ such that $cn^ne^{-n} \leq n! \leq Cn^{n+1}e^{-n}$.
In relation to a proof of the proportion of heads going to 1/2 in the Laplace model, it would be useful to get that there exists $C,c > 0$ such that for all small enough $\epsilon>0$ and all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that $$\binom{n}{\lceil n(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon) \rceil} \leq Cn^C2^n \exp(-c\epsilon^2n)$$

I have tried long and hard to prove this, but have ended up with roofed terms in the exponent which are hard to deal with. Any ideas?

Comment: This is neither here nor there, but I just wanted to say that I've never heard the term "roofed" before and I really like it.

Comment: I'm curious about that $\epsilon$. Do you really need the result to hold for *all* $\epsilon$ and $n$ pairs? If $\epsilon < 1 / \sqrt n$, then I think the result is fairly straightforward, since $\binom n k$ is maximized when $k$ is as close as possible to $n/2$, and the exponential term on the far right will be bounded below. But if $\epsilon$ tends to zero with $n$ somewhat slowly, such as $1 / n^{1/4}$, then the result seems less obvious to me, because the exponential term on the far right will tend to $0$.

Comment: @Aaron Yes I think you are right. I will edit the question and you can write up the comment as an answer, clarifying a few points, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing my comment out to an answer: if we are allowed to choose $\epsilon$ in response to $n$ and need only to prove it for all *small* $\epsilon$, then we get the desired result.

Sketch of proof: For any $n$, fix $\epsilon = 1/ \sqrt n$.

*Claim:* The expression $\binom n k$ is maximized when $k$ is as close to $n/2$ as possible. There are many ways to see why this is the case; I'll omit them here.

For simplicity, I'll assume in the sequel that $n$ is even. By the claim above, we have $$\binom{n}{n \lceil n(\frac 1 2 - \epsilon) \rceil} \leq \binom{n}{n/2}$$
and by Stirling's approximation,
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{n/2} &= \frac{n!}{\left((n/2)! \right)^2} \\
& \leq \frac{Cn^{n+1} e^{-n}}{\left( c(n/2)^{n/2} e^{-n/2} \right)^2} \\ 
&= \frac{Cn \cdot 2^n}{c^2}
\end{align*}
and since $\exp(-c \epsilon^2 n) = \exp(-c)$ is a constant, we can append that term to the right side of the final expression at only the cost of a constant multiplier.